# How to perform onClick action and onswipe operation on same view

Tags: android, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I have a view /view group. I want to show some dialog when user swipes from left to right on that view. And when clicking/touch on that same view i need to send other activity/screen.

Its performing only clicking/touch operation. I used Gesture listener also its not working as i expected.

This is my code

```
 root=(LinearLayout)mView.findViewById(R.id.root_home);
        final GestureDetector gesture = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                                           float velocityY) {
                        //Log.i(Constants.APP_TAG, "onFling has been called!");
                        final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
                        final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
                        final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
                        try {
                            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                                return false;
                            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                                Log.i(Constants.APP_TAG, "Right to Left");


                            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                                Log.i(Constants.APP_TAG, "Left to Right");


                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // nothing
                        }
                        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
                    }
                });

        root.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });

       root.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getActivity()) {
            @Override
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                // Whatever

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                // Whatever

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return mView;
    }

    public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

        private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

        public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
        }

        public void onSwipeRight() {
        }

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

            private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
            private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (distanceX > 0)
                        onSwipeRight();
                    else
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cannot manage swipes, here is a working piece of code. `yourView` is the view you want to attach listener to.

```
yourView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        x1 = event.getX();
                        y1 = event.getY();
                        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        x2 = event.getX();
                        y2 = event.getY();
                        t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2 && (t2 - t1) < CLICK_DURATION) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if ((t2 - t1) >= CLICK_DURATION) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (x1 > x2) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Left swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (x2 > x1) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Right swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } 


                        return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks,Its working for only individual view..but i have viewgroups i want to swipe on viewgroup and that view group contains some many view with onclick listern..

Comment: You can totally setOnTouchListener to LinearLayout as you tried before. I think you should try it as I got it to work in my app

Comment: thanks, what would be the value of CLICK_DURATION to get correct click and swipe.

Comment: You can play and adjust , i don't see all the viewgroup and cannot take into consideration all click events you want to catch

Comment: Glad to hear that, then you can accept the answer as it helped you solve the problem. Just hit the tick to the left of the answer and others will know the code works